# WordPress Blog Shows 404 error on homepage unless you are logged in

Tags: wordpress

My blog `techshali.com` is showing 404 error on homepage. If you visit my blog you are likely to see 404 error but this error is only on homepage and logged in users will not see this error. I don't know why this is happening. Please help me.

Comment: There is a temporary solution for it.
If I switch the theme to default and the again switch back to main theme the problem is solved. But after a few days everything goes as usual.

Answer (score 0):

One reason may be due to the post being selected as "Private" instead of "Published". Have you checked this?